# Transforming "null" in JSON to empty String instead of "None"

Tags: json, string, rust, match

I'm using serde to deserialize a JSON file and one of it's values is a String.
To read it, I'm using:

```
#[serde(default)]
pub key: Option<String>,
```

because in the JSON file I can have `null` (then `Option` handles) or not even pass it (`#serde(default)]` handles it).

The problem I'm having is that when in the `null` case, the `Option` is returning `None`, which is giving me trouble later. I have to later match the Strings and convert to an `i8` like this:

```
let mut transformed: i8 = 0;    
if key.as_ref().unwrap() == "H" {
    transformed = 1;
}
else {
    transformed = -1;    // Case that I'm looking for when null in JSON
}
```

I searched for `match` practices to handle the None, but it's also giving me trouble with the String vs &str problem, so I'm looking for a way of when deserializing, assign an empty String "" instead of `None`, so later I can compare in the same way I'm already doing.

Also would appreciate less verbose solution to directly parse and assign an `i8`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're looking for keeping `Option` and using something like [`unwrap_or_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_default) instead of `unwrap`, or whether you want to get rid of the `Option` altogether and use [`#[serde(default)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#default) on the field.

Comment: @mcarton The `#[serde(default)]` attribute only applies to fields that are completely missing. It won't make a `String` field accept a `null` value.

Comment: Good point, you'd need `deserialize_with` then.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by mcarton in the comments, the easiest solution is to stick with using an `Option<String>` in you struct and use `.unwrap_or_default()` in the code consuming the data. If this isn't an option for you, you can provide a custom deserializer using the `#[serde(deserialize_with=...)]` attribute:

```
use serde_json::from_str;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct A {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "null_to_default")]
    key: String,
}

fn null_to_default<'de, D, T>(de: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    T: Default + Deserialize<'de>,
{
    let key = Option::<T>::deserialize(de)?;
    Ok(key.unwrap_or_default())
}

fn main() {
    let a: A = from_str(r#"{"key": null}"#).unwrap();
    dbg!(a);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=596c2965485d925e3696795db4e8c44b))

Comment: Thanks mcarton and Sven Marnach. I haven't tested the deserialize_with solution, but replacing ".unwrap()" with ".unwrap_or(&"".to_owned())" solved the problem!

Comment: `.unwrap_or(&"".to_owned())` is a bad idea because it always allocates a new string even when it's not needed (because the `Option` is `Some(s)`). `unwrap_or_default` will only allocate a new empty string if the `Option` is `None` (or you can use `.unwrap_or_else(|| &"".to_owned())` if you really want to).

Comment: @Jmb Creating an empty string does not allocate. It only creates a `String` struct on the stack, which is very cheap. What you describe is good practice in general, but it doesn't make any significant difference in this particular case.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `serde_with::DefaultOrNull` (https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.DefaultOnNull.html)